# Pullback to spherical coordinates and intuition on pullbacks in general

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, pullback

Pretty much what the question says. Right. So, to remind everyone, spherical coordinates are:

\begin{align} 
x & = \rho \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) \\ 
y & = \rho \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) \\ 
z & = \rho \cos(\phi) \\ 
\rho^2 & = x^2 +y^2 +z^2 
\end{align}

After computing the pullback, I get the result $d\rho^2 + \rho^2 \sin^2(\phi) d \phi ^2 + \rho^2 d\theta^2 $

(Question 1: Is this computation correct? Is there an easier way to calculate this?)

What is the geometric intuition here? If I had a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ does moving by $\rho$ tell me that I have to adjust my $\phi $ and $\theta$ in my tangent vector? My own intuition tells me that this change of coordinates allows for a sort of different expression of "straightness". Rotating by $\theta$ is very natural in these coordinates but to express a nonradial line in spherical coordinates sounds tricky. So that is how I am sort of justifying this to myself. What are others' intuition on this pullback metric business?

Comment: In your fourth equation, do you mean to have $\rho^2$ on the left hand side, instead of $r^2$?

Comment: You wrote "after computing the pullback," but you didn't say what you're computing the pullback of.

Comment: Yes, I did mean to right $\rho^2$, thanks for that. @Elliot. Jack, sorry. I meant to say the pullback of the standard euclidean metric.

Comment: Pullback of what?? No, your answer looks like you partly got it from a physicist’s or European source where $\phi$ and $\theta$ are reversed. You should expect $\rho\,d\phi$ and $\rho\sin\phi\,d\theta$ if you draw pictures.

Comment: @TedShifrin For what it's worth, I don't think there is a specific European convention for spherical coordinates that is the converse of that used in the US. Maybe the only difference is that we might sometimes use $\lambda$ for the latitude. It seems more likely to be a physics thing, see the two first pictures on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: @TedShifrin pullback of the euclidean metric. This is the Riemannian metric that you place on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I know what the Euclidean metric is, but you should edit your question to make it complete. Have you checked to find the error(s) in your calculation?